# C++ Reinforcement Learning Library

Tags: c++, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have been looking for a C++ Library that implements Reinforcement Learning Algorithms but was not very satisfied with the results.

I found the [Reinforcement Learning Toolbox 2.0](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/ril-toolbox/general/overview.html) from the TU Graz but unfortunately this project is very old and I was unable to get it to compile.

There is also code from [Hado van Hasselt](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~hasselt/index.html). It looks promising but does not seem to be actively maintained.

Which libraries do you use for Reinforcement Learning in C++?

Answer (score 7):

[RL-Glue](http://rl-community.org/wiki/Main_Page) is somewhat of a standard int the reinforcement learning community. [RL-Library](http://library.rl-community.org/wiki/Main_Page) is the part that implements standard algorithms. That said, the most common reinforcement algorithms are so simple that they don't call for any kind of library.